# Deploying Create-React-App applications into different environments

Tags: reactjs, deployment, create-react-app

I've got an app that I'm working on that consists of a Frontend - written using CRA - and a Backend - written in Java. We would like to support deploying this in multiple environments throughout our process, namely:

- Local development machine - This is easy. Just run "npm start" and use the "development" environment
- Local End-to-end tests - these build an infrastructure in Docker consisting of the Frontend, Backend and Database, and runs all of the tests against that
- Development CI system
- QA CI System
- Pre-production System
- Production System

The problem that I've got is - in the myriad of different systems, what is the best way for the Frontend to know where the Backend is? I'm also hoping that the Frontend can be deployed onto a CDN, so if it can be static files with the minimal complexity that would be preferred.

I've got the first two of these working so far - and they work by the use of the `.env` files and having a hard-coded hostname to call.

Once I get into the third and beyond - which is my next job - this falls down, because in each of the cases there is a *different* hostname to be calling, but with the same output of `npm run build` doing the work.

I've seen suggestions of:

- Hard-code every option and determine it based on the current browser location in a big switch statement. That just scares me - not only do I have to maintain my *deployment* properties inside my source code, but the Production source will know the internal hostnames, which is arguably a security risk.
- Run different builds with provided environment variables - e.g. `REACT_APP_BACKEND=http://localhost:8080/backend npm run build`. This will work, but then the code going into QA, PreProd and Prod are actually different and could arguably invalidate testing.
- Adding another Javascript file that gets deployed separately onto the server and is loaded from `index.html`. That again means that the different test environments are technically different code.
- Use DNS Tricks so that the hostnames are the same everywhere. That's just a mess.
- Serve the files from an active web server, and have it dynamically write the URL out somehow. That would work, but we're hoping that the Production one can just be a simple CDN that just serves up static files.

So - what is the best way to manage this?

Cheers